# Dockerfile - stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory": unknown

Tags: docker

I'm working with alpine-node for a NextJS app. I'm trying to Run yarn install. My console returns me:

> stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory": unknown

Here my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:latest
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh"] // I have tried to modify the entrypoin in order to cure the problem
RUN yarn install
COPY . /app  
RUN yarn build
CMD yarn start
```

What's going wrong ? I can't figure it out.

Any hint would be great,

thanks.

Comment: What else have you tried for ENTRYPOINT?

Comment: Usually, Alpine Docker images don't come with bash installed so you have to install it yourself. Try adding the line `RUN apk update && apk add bash` in your Dockerfile (Before `ENTRYPOINT`)

Comment: What about the image `node_alpine:latest` used in the Dockerfile? If it's image `alpine:latest` there is the `/bin/sh`. So check the image `node_alpine:latest` if it was built yourself.

Answer (score 1):

**Try with this first -**

```
$>docker run -it --rm node_alpine:latest
/ # hostname
75b6ddda492f
```

If you get the shell inside the container then your images should also work fine.
Otherwise issue is with the base image (node_alpine:latest)

Comment: anyways I didn't find "node_alpine:latest" directly referenced on docker-hub. So you might try with official image : `node:alpine`

Comment: thanks i'm using alpine node, my tags is the result of some settings problem because of import from filesystem there was no tag on my images etc etc